# HTML select element validate using JavaScript (Have to check each of the options values)?

Tags: javascript, html

What I Have:

```js
var validt = document.getElementById("sel")
if (validt.value = "yes") {
  //do some operations
} else { //do some operations}
```

```html
<label>Employee:</label>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

what I want:
 How Do I want to check those values in JavaScript so do some operations?

Comment: I want to check with if statement if(validat="")

Comment: What do you want to do? Can you please explain

Comment: You have a typo. You're if statement has a single `=` which is for assignment, not comparison. For comparison use `==`.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for a simple typographical error.

Comment: Are you trying to do change event?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var validt = document.getElementById("sel")
if (validt.value === "yes") {
  //do some operations
  console.log("Jay")
} else { //do some operations
console.log("Hell No")
}
```

```html
<label>Employee:</label>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Check your typo, === || instead of  =  in the if...else statement

Comment: Please don't just do a code paste as an answer - please try to explain what you have changed and why, otherwise it becomes a game of spot the difference.  (You can edit your answer to put your comment at the top)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You should use switch case type in a function.

We checked values(from select) in the switch case.

```js
function det(x) {
  switch (x.value) {
    case "yes":
      alert("yes selected");
      break;
    case "no":
      alert("no selected");
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="answer" onChange="det(this)">
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```